# How to programmatically change the background image of an Android Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, sharedpreferences

I have been able to change colour of an activity background (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574678/how-to-change-background-colour-of-an-android-activity)). Now a requirement is to do the same with background image. I mean I can click a button, select an option and change the current Activity background image to the new one.

Here is what I have done:

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;    
private static final String SELECTED_ITEM = "SelectedItem"; 
private Editor sharedPrefEditor;

btnchangeColor = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnchangeColor);
btnchangeColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final CharSequence[] items={getString(R.string.default),getString(R.string.pix1), getString(R.string.pix2))};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            ContentView.this);

    builder.setTitle((getResources().getString(R.string.color_switch)));
    builder.setPositiveButton((R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, getSelectedItem(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                
            wvContent = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvContent);             
            int bg_color=0;

            if(getString(R.string.default).equals(items[which]))
            {                   
                wvContent.setBackgroundColor(0);
                BitmapDrawable bg = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default);
                bg.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
                wvContent.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);                    
                bg_color=R.drawable.default; 
            }
            else if(getString(R.string.pix1).equals(items[which]))
            {
                wvContent.setBackgroundColor(0);
                BitmapDrawable bg = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pix1);
                bg.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
                wvContent.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);                    
                bg_color=R.drawable.pix1;
                }
            else if(getString(R.string.pix2).equals(items[which]))
            {
                wvContent.setBackgroundColor(0);
                BitmapDrawable bg = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pix2);
                bg.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
                wvContent.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);                    
                bg_color=R.drawable.pix2;                   
                }               
            saveSelectedItem(bg_color);
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

Changes are saved and loaded using the following code:

```
//OnCreate
wvContent = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvContent); 
wvContent.setBackgroundColor(getSelectedItem());
...
private int getSelectedItem() {
    if (prefs == null) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    }
    return prefs.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM, -1);
}

private void saveSelectedItem(int which) {
    if (prefs == null) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    }
    sharedPrefEditor = prefs.edit();
    sharedPrefEditor.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM, which);
    sharedPrefEditor.commit();
}
```

The Activity background image does change when it is selected from the Dialog list, BUT the change is not saved and loaded next time when the activity is relaunched.

I have no idea now how to solve this problem. Can you please help? Many thanks.

Comment: kindly explain to me,u want the image change from the user side?when ever user want he will change the image??am i correct?

Comment: Yes. This is kind of reading material, and the user may want to change the background to meet their eyesight need.

Comment: ok then u need to put that image into sdcard..and when ever user need to change the image,he can only change or replace the image within his sdcard..so i mean the image will be change dunamically from the client side..can u get my point and sorry for my english..

Comment: That may be the next step. At this point, I only focus on how to save and retain the background change so that when the app (or activity) starts next time, the background image is still there.

Comment: This is the advice please lets try and let me know if it's worked or not...in your saveSelectedItem(int which) method please remove the following  lines and implement within onCreate method plz try.... if (prefs == null) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    }

Comment: Please see @Hamid Shatu below. It's a possible solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you are setting background after selecting from `Dialog` then you are getting the resource id `R.drawable.pix2` and retrieving the `BitmapDrawable` as follows...

```
wvContent.setBackgroundColor(0);
BitmapDrawable bg = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pix2);
bg.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
wvContent.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);                    
bg_color=R.drawable.pix2;
```

But in `onCreate()` method you are just passing the resource id as below...

```
wvContent.setBackgroundColor(getSelectedItem());
```

where, `getSelectedItem()` returns an `int` value which is a resource id.

Now, set background drawable as follows in `onCreate()` method...

```
wvContent.setBackgroundColor(0);
BitmapDrawable bg = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(getSelectedItem());
bg.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
wvContent.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
```

You can update background from SDCard as follows...

```
    String pathName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/folder/" + "image.jpg";
    Resources res = getResources(pathName);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
    BitmapDrawable backgroundDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);
    wvContent.setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundDrawable);
```

Comment: @HS that's what i m talk in about. +1 up for your _Awesome_ answer

Comment: This appears the most logical. I have tried your instruction but there's no luck. The activity still displays its default background after it relaunches.

Comment: Then you can try first setting `wvContent.setBackgroundColor(0);` then continue above process.

Comment: Many thanks to you, @Hamid Shatu. That does the trick: I works now as I expect. I will accept yours as the answer, but if you don't mind, could you show me how to choose image as background from `sdcard` instead of `drawable`?

Comment: to choose image from sdcard try the following code...                    String pathName = "/sdcard/nogastorebgimage.png";
        Resources res = getResources();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
        BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);
        RelativeLayout rl_main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_main);
        rl_main.setBackgroundDrawable(bd);

Comment: @HamidShatu +1 from me for ur nice answer :)

Comment: Many thanks. The update really helps, but I mean to choose a particular image from sdcard of the user's preference, not a pre-defined.

Comment: To choose image dynamically from SDCard, this link may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856959/android-file-chooser

Comment: @NiamhDoyle ...I think, this link will help you more: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/

Answer (score 4):

add this to your activity.xml:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/iso"
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
```

add this to activity.java:

```
ImageView layout = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background);
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iso);
```

Comment: And how this is used to change the background if user wants?

Comment: when set ImageView as is it will become background of activity

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
WebView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourImage);
```

use this above code, may this help you....