# Set mywallpaper in android after pressed button

Tags: android, wallpaper

I made my own wallpaper and I don't know how to set this when the user clicked over button “SET WALLPAPER”

I wrote:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
```

But not the code, I need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is my solution .... launch with Intent the MyWallPaperService

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
                            intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
                                new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyWallpaperService.class));
                            startActivity(intent);
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background of one `Activity`:

- In the `Activity` layout, setting the root `View` (Normally a `LinearLayour` or `RelativeLayout`) with `android:background="@drawable/yourdrawable"`
- Programatically:

  ```
  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
  ll.setBackgroundDrawable(...)
  ```
- Or with a theme for your app or `Activity`.

In your case, you are interested in changed it programatically, so you would need to use the second option. You need to add a `onClickListener` to your button and inside change the background, something like this:

```
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
            ll.setBackgroundDrawable(...)
        }
    });
```

By the way, to change the background of your activity you do not need use permisions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
```

Here you have similar questions:

[How to programmatically change the background image of an Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603153/how-to-programmatically-change-the-background-image-of-an-android-activity)

[Change Layout-background on click programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989312/change-layout-background-on-click-programmatically)

[Android: Changing Background-Color of the Activity (Main View)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961071/android-changing-background-color-of-the-activity-main-view)

[How to set background color of an Activity to white programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761686/how-to-set-background-color-of-activity-to-white-programmatically)

Comment: but i have a class with image and text in wallpaper

Comment: But you want to set the wallpaper for your app or for the System?

Comment: In my app (wallpapercustom) I want put a button in an activity and  that say "SET WALLPAPER" and would will be change de wallpaper of my phone

Comment: @EliasTimMamaniCanaza I've edited my answer, I thought you want to change the phone wallpaper, not your activity background.